# How to detect if a NSURL can be accessed on a Sandboxed app?

Tags: objective-c, nsurl, appstore-sandbox, entitlements, nsopenpanel

I'm writing an OS X application that has an open panel with a preview accessory view.

The problem is that when I select a file that is not on a folder with sandbox permissions I cannot preview it.

Is there any way to tell if a file can would be restricted by the sandbox permissions before trying to open it?

I already tried `- (BOOL)checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:(NSError **)error`
 of the `NSURL` class but it returns true even when the file is protected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended method is to obtain the path from the URL, convert to a C string, and then call `access` (documented in section 2 of man) to check for the permission you require. E.g., in outline to check for read access:

```
#include <unistd.h>

if (access([[url path] UTF8String], R_OK) == 0)
{
   // have access rights to read
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For those who like to have as less as possible Plain-Old-C Lines in the Code:

```
NSURLIsReadableKey  in NSURL - (BOOL)getResourceValue:(out id *)value forKey:(NSString *)key
```

alternatively

```
NSFileManager - (BOOL)isReadableFileAtPath:(NSString *)path
```

The sandbox will cause these to return NO if it restricts your access and are merely Cocoa-Wrappers around access(). The sandbox will cause these to return NO if it restricts your access.

Comment: This would check whether the "current process can read" or not. What if current process is something else ?

Comment: @ankii That’s the purpose of sandbox that no other process can interfere.

Comment: so one app = one process ? can one app have multiple processes(child ones say)

Comment: @ankii probably best if you ask this in a new question.